# Confusion with Expected Queue Length (Lq) Formulas for M/M/s Model in Queuing theory

Tags: queuing-theory, proofs

I have found two formulas for Expected Queue Length $L_q$ for the M/M/s model regarding Queuing Theory, namely:

1. Found inside the "Introduction to the Operations Research" book made by Hillier Lieberman:

\begin{equation}
L_q = \frac{P_0(\lambda/\mu)^{s}\rho}{s!(1-\rho)^2}
\end{equation}

2. Found on a [people.revoledu.com website](https://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/Queuing/MMs-Queuing-System.html#MMsQueuingSystem) and on a [mathcracker.com website](https://mathcracker.com/multiple-server-model-calculator) (in similar form):

\begin{equation}
L_q = \frac{P_0(\rho)^{s+1}}{(s-1)!(s-\rho)^2}
\end{equation}

Are both of the equations the same? How can one prove it?

I don't have the slightest idea what to do with the $s$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the same, with the caveat that the two sources are using slightly different notation. All symbols other than $\rho$ are the same in both places, but Hillier and Lieberman use $\rho = \frac{\lambda}{s\mu}$ (page 154 in the edition I have) whereas in the linked tutorial they use $\rho=\frac{\lambda}{\mu}.$ Substitute the respective fractions for $\rho$ and both versions of $L_q$ come out the same.

Comment: Dear prof. thanks for your clarification. I never see the first notation ($\rho = \frac{\lambda}{s\mu}$). It seems it is a bit complicated to the second/usual form.

Comment: @A.Omidi It's been a long, long time since I dealt with queueing theory, but I think the Hillier-Lieberman version of $\rho$ was the one I usually encountered when there were multiple servers.

Comment: Thank you a lot Professor, thought my question was inappropriate and naive but It turned out great!

Comment: Dear @prubin, thanks for pointing this out. I will check that ASAP.

Comment: Dear @prubin, I checked this and you are totally right. Thanks for mentioning that. 